# Why does Python detect the symbol "²" as a digit?

Tags: python, string

Can someone say if "²" is a symbol or a digit? (alt+1277, power of two)

```
print("²".isdigit())
# True
print("²".isnumeric())
# True
```

Because Python says it's a digit, but it's not actually a digit. Am I wrong? Or it's a bug?

Comment: It _is_ a digit -- it's clearly the numeral 2.  However it is not ascii.

Comment: japanese kanji digits are digits too. It's just tthat you probably convert it to int

Comment: The key is that neither `isdigit` nor `isnumeric` implies that a string consisting of these values can be used as an argument to, e.g., `int`. If you want to know if a string `s` represents a particular `int` value, don't inspect `s`, try it with `int(s)` and catch an exception if raised.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is [explicitly documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) as a digit:

> str.**isdigit()**
>
> Return `True if all characters in the string are digits and there is at least one character,` False` otherwise. Digits include
> decimal characters and digits that need special handling, such as the
> **compatibility superscript digits**. This covers digits which cannot be
> used to form numbers in base 10, like the Kharosthi numbers. Formally,
> a digit is a character that has the property value Numeric_Type=Digit
> or Numeric_Type=Decimal.

Regarding [Numeric_Type](https://www.unicode.org/L2/L2012/12310-numeric-type-def.html), this is defined by Unicode:

> *Numeric_Type=Digit*
>
> Variants of positional decimal characters (Numeric_Type=Decimal) or sequences thereof. These include **super/subscripts**, enclosed, or decorated by the addition of characters such as parentheses, dots, or commas.

Answer (score 4):

Python is smart enough to tag unicode characters as digits, just because it's possible.

To complete [this good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65041702/6451573), note that you can even get the floating point representation of the character:

```
>>> from unicodedata import numeric
>>> numeric("²")
2.0
```

It's float because there are unicode versions of 1/2, 3/2 ...

(see [How to convert unicode numbers to ints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39710365/how-to-convert-unicode-numbers-to-ints))

Comment: Coming from the C and C++ world, this makes me feel rather ill. Out of interest, what happens with numeric(leminscate) ?

Comment: yeah :) but you don't have to use all the features. Personally I never use unicode in my scripts.

Comment: I'm primarily a Python developer, and it makes be a bit queasy as well :) However, keep in mind that programs that do math are not the only use case for Unicode. Just because something is considered a digit doesn't necessarily mean it should be used *numerically*.

Comment: @chepner: Yes that's a good point and there are parallels in C and C++. E.g. 08 is an invalid integer constant in both languages as the leading 0 denotes octal and 8 is an invalid octal digit. But it's still a digit.

Comment: except that you can do `int("08")` and as the base is specified (default, 10) it will convert to 8 all right

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Your answer shows why does python says it's a digit , because it defines as a float I guess, but I'm asking you , is that a character , symbol or a digit for you (not python)?